# Best Way to Load Pages w/o Reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am working on building a website that will not reload to a new page every time a link is pressed. I want to make something kind of like all enterprise/popular websites. (When looking in the network dev tab: notice that youtube page doesn't completely reload when you click on a link, same with google, same with Facebook for the most part. They all usually just reload the page content and nothing else.)

I would like only the HTML between the body tags to be changed (nothing else: no js,css, no head tags, etc).

It would seem like it is pretty easy. Currently, I am just using ajax to go out and fetch the html of the page, and load that into the body. Done! Not so fast... Three things (my code is at the bottom)

1. The js includes are located at the bottom of the page, right before the closing body and html tags. When looking in the network tab, it shows that the same js is always gotten again and parsed again. How do I prevent that?
2. Some pages will not load styles that are set. (note that all css, js, etc. scripts are the same for every page)
3. I want to make sure that the page is completely reloaded if the user leaves the website.

I am not sure if I am looking for a fix to the way I am doing it, but probably just a completely better different way to do it.

Here is my code:

```
$('a').on('click', function () { //on click of any <a> tag
    var where = $(this).attr('href'); //gets url of the <a> attribute
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: where, //where is the variable defined above
        success: function(a) {
            // load next page
            history.pushState({urlPath: where},"",where); //changes the link of the webpage
            $('body').html(a); //changes the body of the webpage
            document.title = $('#title').text(); //changes the title using some weird irrelevant method
        }
    });
    return false;
});
$(window).on('popstate', function() {//on click of the back or forward button
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: window.location.href, //the url is the url that the back or forward button is set to
        success: function(data) {
            //console.log();
            $('body').html(data);//replaces data
            document.title = $('#title').text();//changes title using weird irrelevant method
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You basically want the pages your loading to not include the javascript etc.  eg.  If your loading normal pages you don't want all the html / head etc loading.  Basically the pages your loading via ajax want to be stripped down, eg.  just `<div>content</div>` etc.

Comment: I believe you are trying to create a `progressive web app`. There is a bunch of things you have to do in order to get it, so I guess it is better you google it

Comment: Batter make use of `single page application frameworks` than making your own, It's far more easier